# Streamwriter throws a system.argumentexception

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I know this question seems strange.

I use .NET Micro Framework to write a small program in C# that use the default emulator to emulate a flash light using 5 buttons on the emulator, using interruptport to raise events.

I coded so that when i pressed the bottom button, all the records stored in an arraylist usagelog will be printed out to a txt file. Very simple and straightforward, i made a Streamwriter instance

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp.txt");
```

But then it throws "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.IO.dll" at this line.

I can't fix this, and I can't understand why there's an argument exception here. The code works fine for a console project in visual C#, but it doesn't in Micro Framework.

Comment: Catch the exception and display `ex.ToString()`, and you may have a big clue.

Comment: that's all it says "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.IO.dll". when ex.ToString() it says System.Argumentexception

Comment: Then check the inner exception. In this case there should be one - same treatment. Until you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Sheesh. What happened to the idea of being nice! http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: MSDN states that an ArgumentException is only thrown in the constructor you are uaing if: 1) The string is empty or 2) The string points to a non-file resource. Perhaps the emulator is assuming #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is the because the FileSystem is different between Windows and the MicroFramework. I was able to get it to run on the Emulator by using some Directory Functions to determine the available directorys.

```
public static void Main()
{
    string  d = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string[] directorys = Directory.GetDirectories(d);
    foreach (var item in directorys )
    {
        Debug.Print(item);
    }

    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("\\WINFS\\temp.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Good Evening");
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

}
```

In the Emulator I came up with

```
 [0]: "\\ROOT"
 [1]: "\\WINFS"
```

`ROOT` did not work but `WINFS` did.